# Parse String for unknown TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, date, time, java-time, datetime-parsing

I'm getting a request parameter with unknown temporal (date, time or timestamp in ISO format) and want to parse it into a `java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor`:

- `LocalDate` when the string represents a date like `"2018-02-28"`
- or `LocalDateTime` when the string represents a timestamp like `"2018-02-28T11:20:00"`

The following attempt results into `DateTimeParseException`:

```
TemporalAccessor dt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parseBest(str, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
```

Deciding on the length of the string or the occurrence of a "T", which `DateTimeFormatter` to use, seems to me a little bit hacky. As well as trying one format after another.

Any better solution?

Comment: Can you list the possible inputs in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `ISO_DATE_TIME` expects a time, as the name indicates. In your case you need to use an optional section in your pattern.

This should work as required:

```
DateTimeFormatter FMT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .optionalStart() //HERE WE INDICATE THAT THE TIME IS OPTIONAL
        .appendLiteral('T')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .toFormatter();

String input = "2018-02-28";
TemporalAccessor dt = FMT.parseBest(input, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
```