# Parse date or datetime both as LocalDateTime in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I need to parse a field which is sometimes given as a date and sometimes as a date/time. Is it possible to use single datatype for this using Java 8 time API?
Currently, I attempted to use a LocalDateTime for it, but for following invocation `LocalDateTime.parse("1986-04-08", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))`
I get a

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 1986-04-08 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

This is part of some generic parser accepting a date/datetime parse pattern as configuration option. So e.g. following solution with hardcoded parsing pattern

```
if ("yyyy-MM-dd".equals(pattern)) {
    LocalDate.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))).atStartOfDay()
}
```

is not an option for me.

Any other suggestions how to code it in a clean way are welcome.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026914/parse-string-for-unknown-temporalaccessor

Comment: `LocalDate.parse("1986-04-08", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")).atStartOfDay();`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just create custom formatter with the builder [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[ HH:mm:ss]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
        .toFormatter();
```

This formatter uses the `[]` brackets to allow optional parts in the format, and adds the default values for hour `HOUR_OF_DAY`, minute `MINUTE_OF_HOUR` and second `SECOND_OF_MINUTE`.

note: you can ommit, minutes and seconds, just providing the hour is enough.

And use it as usual.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse("1994-05-13", formatter);
LocalDateTime localDateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse("1994-05-13 23:00:00", formatter);
```

This outputs the correct date time with default hours of 0 (starting of the day).

```
System.out.println(localDateTime1); // 1994-05-13T00:00
System.out.println(localDateTime2); // 1994-05-13T23:00
```

Answer (score 5):

Jose's answer using `parseDefaulting` is nice. There's also another alternative, if you don't want to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

First you create your formatter with an optional section - in this case, the time-of-day part, delimited by `[]`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[ HH:mm:ss]");
```

Then you call `parseBest`, providing the `String` to be parsed and a list of method references:

```
TemporalAccessor parsed = fmt.parseBest("1986-04-08", LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
```

In this case, it'll first try to create a `LocalDateTime`, and if it's not possible, it'll try to create a `LocalDate` (if none is possible, it'll throw an exception).

Then, you can check which type is returned, and act accordingly:

```
LocalDateTime dt;
if (parsed instanceof LocalDateTime) {
    // it's a LocalDateTime, just assign it
    dt = (LocalDateTime) parsed;
} else if (parsed instanceof LocalDate) {
    // it's a LocalDate, set the time to whatever you want
    dt = ((LocalDate) parsed).atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
}
```

If the result is a `LocalDate`, you can choose to call `atStartOfDay()`, as suggested by others, or change to a specific time-of-day, such as `atTime(LocalTime.of(10, 30))` for 10:30 AM, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late for the answer, but it can help others...

Since the LocalDateTime you need to set a time, otherwise you can use just the LocalDate, I searched for LocalDateTime built-in solution to handle this.
I didn't found, however I used this following approach:

```java
// For specific date (the same as the question)
LocalDateTime specificDate LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(1986, 4, 8), LocalTime.MIN);
```

**Other examples:**

```java
// For the start of day
LocalDateTime startToday = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MIN));

// For the end of day
LocalDateTime endOfToday = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MAX));
```

This way you don't need to use a formatter. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jose Da Silva's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323017/parse-date-or-datetime-both-as-localdatetime-in-java-8/49324132#49324132):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(' ') // might be 'T' in your case
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    .optionalEnd()
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
    .toFormatter()
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT); // parse STRICT instead of SMART!
```

Usage:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse("1994-05-13", formatter);
LocalDateTime localDateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse("1994-05-13 23:00:00", formatter);
```